# Encode a list in ASCII in Python

Tags: python

I would like to encode a list in ASCII.

My list:

```
data = {u'ismaster': True, u'maxWriteBatchSize': 1000, u'ok': 1.0, u'maxWireVersion': 3, u'minWireVersion': 0}
```

My goal:

```
data = {'ismaster': True, 'maxWriteBatchSize': 1000, 'ok': 1.0, 'maxWireVersion': 3, 'minWireVersion': 0}
```

Currently I do this:

```
>>>data_encode = [x.encode('ascii') for x in data]
>>>print(data_encode)
['maxWireVersion', 'ismaster', 'maxWriteBatchSize', 'ok', 'minWireVersion']
```

See [Website to convert a list of strings](http://www.kennethreitz.org/essays/convert-a-list-of-strings-to-utf-8-in-python)

I lost some values with this method.

Comment: `data` is not a `list` but a `dict`

Comment: Why do you want this?  Having your strings in Unicode (the `u'...'` prefix) is usually a good thing.

Comment: It's to do a insert in database

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you are converting to an actual list, but you originally had a dictionary.  Just do this:

```
data = {key.encode("ascii"): value for key, value in data.items()}
```

You were using a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), but what you wanted was a [dict](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

The 'u' in front of the string values means the string has been represented as [unicode](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html). It is a way to represent more characters than normal ASCII.

You will end up with problems if your dictionary contains special characters

```
strangeKey = u'Ознакомьтесь с документацией'
```

represented as `u'\u041e\u0437\u043d\u0430\u043a\u043e\u043c\u044c\u0442\u0435\u0441\u044c \u0441 \u0434\u043e\u043a\u0443\u043c\u0435\u043d\u0442\u0430\u0446\u0438\u0435\u0439'`

```
 asciirep = strangeKey.encode("ascii")
```

will raise this error

```
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xd0' in ...
```

If you still want it, but with the risk of raising a few exceptions you can use the following

- From Python 2.7 and 3 onwards, you can just use the dict comprehension syntax directly:

  `d = {key.encode("ascii"): value for (key, value) in data.items()}`
- In Python 2.6 and earlier, you need to use the dict constructor :

  `d = dict((key.encode("ascii"), value) for (key, value) in data.items())`